# How to unit test a repository layer method that uses Entity Framework to create objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I have a repository in my application that looks something like this:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    void CreateUser(User user);
    void Save();
}

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public void CreateUser(User user)
    {
        // UsersContext is injected through Unity
        if(user != null)
            this.UsersContext.Users.Add(user);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        this.UsersContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I am follwing [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx) MSDN article on unit testing using Entity Framework. 
My test method looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateUser_Test()
{
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<User>>();

    var mockContext = new Mock<UsersContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Users).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    var repo = new UserRepository(mockContext.Object);
    repo.CreateUser(new User {Name = "Sample User", Age = 23});
    repo.Save();

    // Assert fails, nothing is added to the mocked DbSet.
    Assert.AreEqual(1, mockSet.Object.Users.Count());
}
```

I am not able to test if the object I am trying to create is really added to the mocked `DbSet`. The MSDN article does not help either, it just tests that the methods are called and does not test that the object is added to the mocked `DbSet`. Is there any way I can verify that the object I created is added to the mocked `DbSet`?

Comment: What you are trying to do isn't unit testing it is integration testing.

Comment: You don't need to test that the object is added to the mocked `DbSet` - that's the responsibility of the Entity Framework. Your code is just responsible for making sure the Entity Framework is invoked correctly. (e.g., You just want to make sure that `Save` invokes `SaveChanges` on the underlying context.)

Comment: That is what I am trying not to do. I am trying to mock the `DbSet` in-memory and adding objects to it instead of the actual database. I suppose this is not the right way to do this?

Comment: If you're using EF6 or better, [MSDN has an article on mocking out a DbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx).  Generally, the above holds: you trust your dependencies to do what they say (and perhaps tests to make sure that they're invoked properly).

Comment: Well, that seems really ineffective and a lot of effort to just verify that I actually call a method. Should I even bother to unit test these methods?

Comment: Why does it seem ineffective? Your repository is an abstraction to decouple calling code from the Entity Framework - it's sole purpose in life is to just pass information along to the Entity Framework.

Comment: You should not need to test Entity Framework... just test that the right methods are called within your repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing a non-query scenario (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx#nonQuery). `Moq` has the `Verify` method for this purpose:

```
 mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<User>()), Times.Once());
 mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
```

As an aside, you probably don't want the `Save()` method on your repository. I'd suggest investigating the Unit of Work pattern, which will allow you to coordinate changes across different repositories by ensuring they all share the same context.